# How to execute a Powershell script in parallel

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-5.1

I have a powershell script which is run to connect to remote servers and execute a script. I am passing an argument as well. Is there a way to run this in parallel, passing the correct ids responding to each STORES. The powershell version is 5 in the system.

```
$storeids = Get-Content 'D:\StoreMap.json'  -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$storeids | Select-Object -Property STORE, ID | ForEach-Object {
    $computer = 'IN' + $_.STORE + 'test.org'
    $ID = $_.ID
    $script = 'D:\test.ps1'
    Write-Host "Started running the script on Store" + $computer

    try {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -FilePath $script -ArgumentList $ID
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into the [PSParallel](https://github.com/powercode/PSParallel) module. Windows Powershell (version 5.x or earlier) does not have any built-in parallel capability.

Comment: You can run each computer as a job - `Start-Job` then use a loop to check when the resulting jobs finish and pick up the results. I do this to query all the Domain Controller event logs in parallel

Comment: `invoke-command computer1,computer2,computer3 script.ps1`

Comment: @JeffZeitlin invoke-command runs in parallel with an array of computernames.

Comment: But I would need to pass a relative argument for each computer. So for computer1, I would need to pass it's relative ID1, for computer2, ID2 etc.

Comment: What does `'IN' + $_.STORE + 'test.org'` end up looking like? Missing dots?

Comment: It ends up like 'IN1111test.org', STORE is a 4 digit integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a hash table to lookup the ID based on the remote computers name and then call them in parallel with `Invoke-Command`.

Two things to note

1. Update the hostname property if the assumption is incorrect (make it match each $env:computername)
2. Update D:\test.ps1 to use the lookup table instead of the passed in argument

also see inline comments for details.

```
$storeids = Get-Content 'D:\StoreMap.json'  -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

# The assumption is IN + $_.Store is exactly the remote systems computer name, stored as Hostname property
# The ComputerName property is the fqdn for the Invoke-Command call
$selectprops = '*',
                @{n='Hostname';e={"IN$($_.Store)"}},
                @{n='ComputerName';e={"IN$($_.Store)test.org"}}

# Create a lookup table. Each remote system will be able to extract their own ID from this table via it's computername
$storetable = $storeids |
    Select-Object $selectprops |
        Group-Object -Property Hostname -AsHashTable

# Instead of using a passed in argument, use $using:storetable to grab a local copy of the table and then
# reference it with $localtable[$env:computername]
# Silence errors to prevent interruption and capture any errors to $errors (appended due to +)
$icmparams = @{
    ComputerName  = $storetable.Name
    FilePath      = 'D:\test.ps1'
    ErrorAction   = 'SilentlyContinue'
    ErrorVariable = '+errors'
    ThrottleLimit = 64 # 32 by default
}

$results = Invoke-Command @icmparams

# output collected in $results
$results 

# check any errors
$errors

<# D:\test.ps1

$localtable = $using:storetable
$id = $localtable[$env:computername].ID
"Computer: $env:Computername  ID: $id"

#>
```

Comment: Hey Doug,, thank you so much for taking time out for this. Here, Is "selectprops" storing all the Stores mapped in the json file? I tried to WriteHost to check but it does not seem to be printing anything.

Comment: It takes all the properties from $storeid and adds two additional properties. ```$selectprops = '*',
                @{n='Hostname';e={"IN$($_.Store)"}},
                @{n='ComputerName';e={"IN$($_.Store)test.org"}}```

Comment: I feel like I'm really bad at this but
ComputerName  = $storetable.ComputerName,
this seems to be null or empty. I tried to print $storetable.values, and it prints out fine, but $storetable.ComputerName does not.

Comment: You are right. It should be $storetable.Name

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this

```
Get-Content 'D:\StoreMap.json' -Raw |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object -Property STORE, ID |
    ForEach-Object {
        $computer = 'IN'+$_.STORE+'test.org'
        $ID= $_.ID
    
        Write-Host "Started running the script on Store " + $computer

        $ScriptBlock = {
            Param([string] $ID)

            #Your remote code here, most likely content of D:\test.ps1
        }
        
        Start-Job -Name "Script on $($computer)" -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -Args $ID
    }
Get-Job | Wait-Job
$return += Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: It's giving the following:

Supply values for the following parameters process 0

Comment: What exactly is requesting an argument ?

Comment: So I'm passing an argument/parameter of $ID to the 'content of D:\test.ps1'
When I put the actual code of test.ps1 as you have requested, when I try to run it, it is giving me :
 Supply values for the following parameters process 0